# How to pass List<string> to constructor in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

How can Pass List to a constructor

I trying like this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        step2 st2 = new step2(list);
    }
```

But what to write  in constructor definition

```
 public step2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Change it to `public step2(List<string> list)`

Comment: But what do you want to do with this list in constructor?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a parameter in the constructor.  For example.

```
 public step2(List<Type> list) 
 {

 }
```

Where `Type` is your list type, i.e. `List<string>`

Answer (score 3):

It is that simple

```
public step2(List<string> list)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I highly recommend to read a book about the basics of c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a constructor for the `step2` type that takes a `List<T>`

```
public step2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Should be:

```
public step2(List<T> list)
{
    //Do something with list
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

[Constructors C# Programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx) should come in handy

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
public step2(List<Type> list) {

}
```

But good practice is to set `IList` as an argument type.

```
public step2(IList<Type> list) {

}
```

You can read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058511/passing-an-interface-instead-of-an-object-instance) about passing interfaces instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to constructor either List or any class/interface that List inhereit from. For example IList will be good as well.

```
public step2(List<T> list){ }


public step2(IList<T> list){ }
```

T is a Type.

Answer (score 0):

You could even just do:

```
public step2(List<T> list){}
```

To use the function as a generic funciton for all List item :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be your class constructor to accommodate List:

```
public step2(List<T> list)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And you can call this class as follows:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();  // You can choose your own data type.
step2 obj = new step2(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on what class step2 inherits from or how you use it. In other words - if your class step2 needs a default constructor you should *not* replace the constructor but add another one:

```
public step2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public step2(IList<String> stringList) : this()
{
    // do something with stringList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A

    {
    List<string> listParam1 = new List<string>();

    public A(List<string> ListParam)
    {
        listParam1 = ListParam;
    }

}
```

This is how a parameterized constructor looks like.

And you can initialize it as following:

```
    List<string> param = new List<string>();
    param.Add("One");
    param.Add("Two");
    A obj = new A(param);
```

Let me know if this was helpful.